# What to do when you find that an answer was from another person

Tags: discussion

I just gave someone credit for a question I had and then noticed that the answer was given (exactly) by another person a few years ago.  Here is my question:

[Hide div when Save/Open box appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567877/hide-div-when-save-open-box-appears/40567961?noredirect=1#comment68373183_40567961)

and you can see the accepted answer is exactly the same given by another person 5 years ago...here

What is your policy on this?

[Is it possible to catch browser's File Open/Save dialog event using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197955/is-it-possible-to-catch-browsers-file-open-save-dialog-event-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

Flag as plagiarism with a link to the original answer. You can blow the whistle on them too by leaving a comment stating as much — this lets others know that the answer was not original and points them to the real original.

And, since you're the question asker, flag your own question as a duplicate now that you're aware it has been answered to your satisfaction elsewhere.

I can wait for you to flag before deleting the copy and marking your question as a duplicate if you'd like.

Comment: ok..I just flagged it....thanks